# How to solve this Bayes' theorem word problem

Tags: bayes-theorem

According to a study in a medical journal, 202 of a sample of 5,990 middle-aged men had developed diabetes. It also found that men who were very active (burning about 3,500 calories daily) were a fifth as likely to develop diabetes compared with men who were sedentary. Assume that one-fourth of all middle-aged men are very active, and the rest are classified as sedentary. What is the probability that a middle-aged man with diabetes is very active? (Round your answer to four decimal places.)

$$
P(a|d)=\frac{P(d|a)p(a)}{P(d)}
$$
$P(d)=\frac{202}{5990}$

Could someone break down for me how to do this one? I have done all the other ones on my homework but this one has me stuck as I am not sure what to categorize as what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want $P(a|d)$ where $a$ means active, $d$ means diabetic. Then Baye's rule gives
$$
P(a|d)=\frac{P(d|a)p(a)}{P(d)}
$$
We know $P(d)=\frac{202}{5990}$. $P(a)=1/4$ and $P(d|a)$ we need to figure out. But 
$$
P(d)=1/4P(d|a)+3/4p(d|s)=1/4P(d|a)+3/4*5P(d|a)
$$
Can you finish from here?

Comment: What is p(d|s)?

Comment: So yeah I guess I am still pretty confused, I am sorry about that

Comment: it is the probability of being diabetic given sedentary

Comment: So are you telling me it is 3/4 or do I need to still find it and 3/4 is only what I multiply it by?

Comment: I am sorry if these are dumb questions I am still pretty new to learning this

Comment: @user344249 I didn't calculate it; I just wanted to show you how to do it. Solve the 1 equation for the final unknown you need to apply Baye's rule.

Answer (score 0):

P(D&A)/P(A) = 1/5*P(D&A')/P(A') 
I am given P(A) = 1/4, so this can be reduced to 
 P(D&A)/(1/4) = 1/5*P(D&A')/(3/4) 
 15*P(D&A) = P(D&A')

The probability I am interested in is 
 P(A|D) = P(D&A)/P(D) 
 = P(D&A)/(P(D&A) + P(D&A')) 
 = P(D&A)/(P(D&A) + 15*P(D&A)) 
 = 1/16

The probability that a man who developed diabetes is very active is 0.0625.